# Is there an equivalent to the Klein-Gordon and Dirac Equations for Vector and other fields?

Tags: field-theory, vector-fields, dirac-equation, klein-gordon-equation, higher-spin

The Klein-Gordon equation describes a scalar field, and the Dirac Equation describes a spinor field. Is there an equivalent equation for a vector field? As well as spin 3/2 and spin 2 tensor fields? Or do you always use other means to describe the evolution of other fields. If so, how do you describe Vector and other tensor fields evolutions.

Side question, do vector fields have complex number components in QFT? If so, how are they different from Spinor fields. And if not, how are they different from classical vector fields?

Comment: For massless vector fields you have the Helmholtz equation, as derived from Maxwell's equations.

Comment: See [Proca equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proca_action), [Bargmann–Wigner equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bargmann–Wigner_equations), and [Joos–Weinberg equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joos–Weinberg_equation).

Answer (score 0):

The comments already provided very useful references. I just would like to make an explicit example in $j=1$ case. Consider the Maxwell Lagrangian
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L} =-\frac{1}{4} F_{\mu \nu} F^{\mu \nu},
\end{equation}
with $F_{\mu \nu}=\partial_{\mu} A_{\nu}-\partial_{\nu} A_{\mu}$ and the equations of motions are
\begin{equation}
\partial_{\mu} F^{\mu \nu}=0.
\end{equation}
The Maxwell Lagrangian is invariant under Lorentz transformations if the field $A_{\mu}$ transforms covariantly
\begin{equation}
A_{\mu} \mapsto A_{\mu}^{'}= \Lambda^{\mu}_{\nu} A^{\nu}.
\end{equation}
Now using $\Lambda^{\mu}_{\nu}$ you may calculate the Pauli-Lubanski operator and realize the field $A_{\mu}$ must have helicity 1. The procedure I showcased can be generalized to any spin:

1. Start from a Lorentz invariant Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}(\Phi)$ ($\Phi$ can be any type of field).
2. Find a representaion for the Lorentz transformation of $\Phi$.
3. Construct the P-L operator.
4. Obtain the spin.

*side question*: If your inquiring about the existence of complex vector fields the answer is yes! The simplest example I can think of is the $W$ boson, which is a complex massive vector (spin=1) boson, in the Standard Model.